# Multiple apps, single codebase

Tags: android

We made an app for a client of us but he wants to sell his app to his clients as a whitelabel app. It has to be almost the same app (only different API url, colors and a different package name). What would be a smart way to do this? I don't want to change every app code when there is a new feature etc. I just want to change the code once for all the apps.

Comment: You may be interested in build variants and flavors https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html?hl=en-419

Comment: @Héctor ++, This is exactly what you need

Comment: But I can't use different package names for this, right?

Comment: Nevermind, you can use `applicationId`. Thanks a lot! I will try it.

Comment: With different flavors/build type you can change the package name: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html

Comment: Another problem, I see how to define sourcesets but whats the best practice for the productFlavors? For example, in the code I just want to use a single resource Id for the API url like R.string.api_base_url.

Comment: @BartBergmans you can duplicate this ID(R.string.api_base_url) in diffrent res subfolders (like this, code screenshot http://prntscr.com/gti5k4). Main rule for it, is exclude R.string.api_base_url from main/res folder to avoid duplication

Comment: And in 'flavour1/res' and 'flavour2/res' folders you can create file 'values/strings.xml' and put to it your  R.string.api_base_url value

Comment: The resource folder doesn't seem to work. It doesn't use the strings in the strings file and it can't find the colors in the colors.xml. I used the same structure as @HankMoody mentioned.

Comment: @BartBergmans can you provide your app level build.gradle file and screenshot of your res folder. If you do all in right way, you'll see smal annotation on file `(flavourName)` (like this http://prntscr.com/gtkfs8)

Comment: @BartBergmans and don't forget to create res folder similar to this http://prntscr.com/gtkhgn and create your res file for each of flavour

Comment: @HankMoody I have the same structure as you, I believe. https://i.imgur.com/TF5TXw5.png

Comment: @BartBergmans and your app gradle file?

Comment: ... I forgot to make the `values` directory...

Comment: @BartBergmans hehe, yes) even I did not notice, I hope everything will work now

Comment: I was searching for the problem with a coworker for over an hour... Everything works now, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm working on a project similar to this. I found that product flavor is very useful in this scenario.

As for package name, use different `applicationId` in every flavor. For the displayed app name, create different string-resource for every flavor and use string resource in `AndoridManifest > application > android:label`.

You can always refer to `BuildConfig.FLAVOR` in your java code to determine which flavor you're currently in if needed.

Some additional resource:
- [Build Variants](https://www.google.com.tw/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwi93JjgmdnWAhXHsJQKHalUDpsQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fstudio%2Fbuild%2Fbuild-variants.html&usg=AOvVaw2hcXT9Zfv-ip49vFV3sgmZ)